# Customizing admin-site: delete_selected

Tags: python, django, templates, admin

I'm working on recreating the admin site to match the theme of the current website and it's been fine up till now, but when I try to select multiple users and use the "delete selected users" action nothing happens.

I have a bit of code, so I have it pasted [here](http://pastie.org/8943101)

**The button is called in admin/actions.html on line 4.**

From reading the admin-site's source I was able to find the method `delete_selected` in `admin/actions.py`.I have only been copying and pasting tags from the original admin-site templates to fit my new ones with the site's style, so I can't figure out why the method isn't being passed.

Here's apicture of the finished page, where everything works except that `Go` button.

[image: a picture]

I feel like there might be a way to recreate a template tag to do it for me but I'm not sure what to call or how ?

The check boxes each have the object's `ID` as values but I'm not sure why it's not being passed to the 'go' button there.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, it was the simplest thing. I forgot to include the `form` surrounding the table. I hope this question will be helpful to anyone looking to customize the admin-site in the future.

Thanks!